# after the command sudo apt-get upgrade i will get the error message?

Tags: upgrade

```
  Processing triggers for man-db ...
  Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.0.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: No its giving the same problem after typing all the above commands

Comment: Is not it work?